# Join 2 identical tables to perform a textfull search in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 2 tables exactly alike: **table1** and **table2**, I need to perform related table1, and now I'm just working with table1 whit the following query.

```
    select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                table1.slug as slugpost,
                table1.titulo,
                table1.id,
                table1.id_usu,
                table1.id_cat,
                table1.slug,
                table1.fecha,
                table1.html,
                table1.hit,
                table1.etiquetas,
                table1.status as table1tatus,
                categorias.nombre,
                categorias.slug as slugcategoria,
                categorias.icon,
                usuarios.id as idusuarios,
                usuarios.usuario
                    from table1 
                        LEFT JOIN usuarios
                            on table1.id_usu = usuarios.id
                        LEFT JOIN categorias on categorias.id=table1.id_cat
                        WHERE
                    MATCH(titulo, etiquetas, html) AGAINST ('".$query."')
                    limit 1,5;
```

The query works fine, but as you can see, just search on table1.

**Table1** keep the old table1 from my site (since post 0 to 127000) and **table2** is the new table to the new post (since post 127001 onwards).

**EDIT**
I tried tu use **UNION** but I have not been able to make it work, MYSQL says  **Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list**.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                    t.slug as slugpost,
                    t.titulo,
                    t.id,
                    t.id_usu,
                    t.id_cat,
                    t.fecha,
                    t.html,
                    t.hit,
                    t.etiquetas,
                    t.status as table1tatus,
                    categorias.nombre,
                    categorias.slug as slugcategoria,
                    categorias.icon,
                    usuarios.id as idusuarios,
                    usuarios.usuario
FROM
(
SELECT table1.slug,table1.titulo,table1.id,table1.id_usu,table1.id_cat,table1.fecha,table1.html,table1.hit,table1.etiquetas,table1.status FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2.slug,table2.titulo,table2.id,table2.id_usu,table2.id_cat,table2.fecha,table2.html,table2.hit,table2.etiquetas,table2.status FROM table2
) t
 LEFT JOIN usuarios on t.id_usu = usuarios.id
 LEFT JOIN categorias on categorias.id=t.id_cat
 WHERE
   MATCH(titulo, etiquetas, html) AGAINST ('dvdrip latino')
   limit 1,5;
```

I have also run the following command

```
 ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `test` (`title`, `tags`, `html`); 
 ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `test2` (`title`, `tags`, `html`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so ,by combining your tables in subselect

```
SELECT 
t.slug as slugpost
,...
FROM
(
SELECT * FROM table1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2 
) t
 LEFT JOIN usuarios on t.id_usu = usuarios.id
 LEFT JOIN categorias on categorias.id=t.id_cat
 WHERE ...
```

To use fulltext search you should add fulltext index for your columns for both tables

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `test` (`titulo`, `etiquetas`, `html`); 
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `test2` (`titulo`, `etiquetas`, `html`);
```

Another way to use fulltext index you can write union query as below by using `MATCH()` individually for each query in subselect

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
t.slug as slugpost,
t.titulo,
t.id,
t.id_usu,
t.id_cat,
t.fecha,
t.html,
t.hit,
t.etiquetas,
t.status as table1tatus,
categorias.nombre,
categorias.slug as slugcategoria,
categorias.icon,
usuarios.id as idusuarios,
usuarios.usuario
FROM
(
SELECT table1.slug,table1.titulo,table1.id,table1.id_usu,table1.id_cat,table1.fecha,table1.html,table1.hit,table1.etiquetas,table1.status FROM table1
WHERE MATCH(`title`, `tags`, `html`) AGAINST ('dvdrip latino')
UNION
SELECT table2.slug,table2.titulo,table2.id,table2.id_usu,table2.id_cat,table2.fecha,table2.html,table2.hit,table2.etiquetas,table2.status FROM table2
WHERE MATCH(`title`, `tags`, `html`) AGAINST ('dvdrip latino')
) t
LEFT JOIN usuarios on t.id_usu = usuarios.id
LEFT JOIN categorias on categorias.id=t.id_cat
limit 1,5;
```

> The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some
>   FULLTEXT index definition for the table, unless this MATCH() is IN
>   BOOLEAN MODE. Boolean-mode searches can be done on nonindexed columns,
>   although they are likely to be slow.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I have tried this http://tny.cz/b8c5ab34 but MYSQL says : #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list. When I try this http://tny.cz/17868255 says Duplicate column name 'slug'. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, selecting slug two times was my bad, I'm updating my answer and what I tried whit your suggest, but MYSQL still says #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list.

Comment: @josesanchez are you sure your table type is `MyISAM`  ?

Comment: @josesanchez see my updated answer hope it works well

Comment: It works, thanks!.. one more thing please, that query is slow, takes 3 seconds to load.

Comment: @josesanchez can you post the `EXPLAIN` plan for your query `EXPLAIN SELECT your whole query` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52025/discussion-between-m-khalid-junaid-and-jose-sanchez)

Comment: M Khalid please go to chat, one problem whit your latest query

Answer (score 0):

You do heve the column `slug` twice in the select list, and this is not permitted in subqueries. Remove one occurence:

```
FROM
(
SELECT table1.slug,table1.titulo,table1.id,table1.id_usu,table1.id_cat,table1.fecha,table1.html,table1.hit,table1.etiquetas,table1.status FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2.slug,table2.titulo,table2.id,table2.id_usu,table2.id_cat,table2.fecha,table2.html,table2.hit,table2.etiquetas,table2.status FROM table2
) t
```